# Is there a smart way to use large numbers in C++

Tags: c++, prime-factoring

Since the University is closed and all exams are cancelled due to Corona, I started programming a prime factorization algorithm in C++. Is there a way to use bigger numbers than `unsigned long long int`? But I must be able to input the number via terminal and calculate with it.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
unsigned long long int number = 1;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    while(1){
        std::cout << "Please enter a number: ";
            unsigned long long int counter = 2;
            unsigned long long int root = 1;
            int err = scanf("%llu",&number);
            if(err != 1){
                number = 1;
                std::cerr << "NOPE" << std::endl;
                return 1;
            }else{
            std::cout << "Prime factors of  " << number << " are: "<<  std::endl;
            if(number < 2){
                number = 1;
                root = 1;
            }else{
                root = sqrt(number);
            }
            while(number != 1){
                // If number % counter == 0, counter must be a prime factor!
                if(number % counter == 0){
                    number = number / counter;
                    root = sqrt(number);
                    std::cout << counter <<  std::endl;
                // If number is smaller than root it must be the last prim factor!  
                }else if(number < root || number < counter){
                    std::cout << number <<  std::endl;
                    break;
                }else{
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you manage to find an algorithm that's better than O(N) then the university will change its name in honour of you.

Comment: Look at the large number library that's part of the Boost distribution. Learning how to use Boost is great for your market value. And it's a steep learning curve.

Comment: Search for the terms "big number," "multiprecision integer," etc. and see what turns up!

Comment: A starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic

Comment: The right way: get a large integer library which handles arbitrary size numbers. The smart way: python (Special note: I deliberately use python for large scale algorithms or integer math problems, because if performance becomes an issue, I know I'm already on the wrong path. They're all about working smarter, not harder.)

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: After some searching I found a good answer for conversion of arbitarty-length decimal strings into binary sequences; after that it's just pretending you have really huge binary registers and implementing add, mult algorithms: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11007021/11547576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GMP is a very high performance library for arbitrary precision integer math in C, and it can also be used in C++. There is a string conversion function which will allow you to accept input from the terminal or other string sources.

https://gmplib.org/

Questions on using GMP for prime factorization already [exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301434/factor-a-large-number-efficiently-with-gmp) on Stack Overflow too :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [boost multi-precision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multiprecision/) library?

Comment: FYI I almost flagged it as not an answer. In future I recommend to at least explain why you suggest this library.

Comment: This upvote is mine. I think the answer is useful (despite it being laconic); the Boost library is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want to understand and create a good code for doing this stuff you have to study a very important Math topic "Number Theory". A good book could be  [Kraft,Washington's one](https://www.amazon.it/Introduction-Number-Theory-Cryptography/dp/1138063479). Check it out and  study and you will see that thanks base rapresentation and number theory some calculus will be more efficient and easier.